# Sonarqube Service does not start

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

I installed the database and try to start the Service.

`Win2003 Server / MySQL 4.1`

After that I get the following error when opening the Website:

```
Sonar installed.
Starting the Sonar service...
--> Wrapper Started as Service
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2014.03.28 11:06:42 INFO  [o.s.a.Connectors]  HTTP connector is enabled on port 9000
2014.03.28 11:06:42 INFO  [o.a.c.h.Http11Protocol]  Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2014.03.28 11:06:42 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardService]  Starting service Tomcat
2014.03.28 11:06:42 INFO  [o.a.c.c.StandardEngine]  Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2014.03.28 11:06:43 INFO  [o.a.c.s.ContextConfig]  No global web.xml found
Sonar started.
2014.03.28 11:06:45 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ServerImpl]  SonarQube Server / 4.1.2 / 765bfba09cd0ef6098cd733b93e1934091e7df7d
2014.03.28 11:06:45 INFO  [o.s.c.p.Database]  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://vwagwosie541.wob.vw.vwg:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
2014.03.28 11:06:46 INFO  [o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  SonarQube home: D:\Programme\sonarqube-4.1.2
2014.03.28 11:06:46 INFO  [o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  Deploy dir: D:\Programme\sonarqube-4.1.2\web\deploy
2014.03.28 11:06:46 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins...
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 1.5 / a8bdbe7769b7b9096af2ef4119ee437c49266de1
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin JaCoCo / 1.5 / a8bdbe7769b7b9096af2ef4119ee437c49266de1
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin English Pack / 4.1.2 / 765bfba09cd0ef6098cd733b93e1934091e7df7d
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Maven Batch Plugin / 4.1.2 / 765bfba09cd0ef6098cd733b93e1934091e7df7d
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Surefire / 1.5 / a8bdbe7769b7b9096af2ef4119ee437c49266de1
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Duplications / 4.1.2 / 765bfba09cd0ef6098cd733b93e1934091e7df7d
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Checkstyle / 1.5 / a8bdbe7769b7b9096af2ef4119ee437c49266de1
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin PMD / 1.5 / a8bdbe7769b7b9096af2ef4119ee437c49266de1
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Java / 1.5 / a8bdbe7769b7b9096af2ef4119ee437c49266de1
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Core / 4.1.2 / 765bfba09cd0ef6098cd733b93e1934091e7df7d
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Database Cleaner / 4.1.2 / 765bfba09cd0ef6098cd733b93e1934091e7df7d
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Squid for Java / 1.5 / a8bdbe7769b7b9096af2ef4119ee437c49266de1
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Design / 4.1.2 / 765bfba09cd0ef6098cd733b93e1934091e7df7d
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.PluginDeployer]  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 4.1.2 / 765bfba09cd0ef6098cd733b93e1934091e7df7d
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins done: 531 ms
2014.03.28 11:06:47 INFO  [o.s.s.p.ApplicationDeployer]  Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2014.03.28 11:06:48 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Start components...
2014.03.28 11:06:48 INFO  [o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector]  Initializing Hibernate
2014.03.28 11:06:49 ERROR [o.s.s.p.PlatformLifecycleListener]  Fail to start server
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in sonar.active_rule_param_changes for column new_value. Found: text, expected: mediumtext
at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1130) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1341) ~[hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867) ~[hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar:3.3.2.GA]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar:3.4.0.GA]
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar:3.4.0.GA]
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52) ~[ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar:3.0 Final Release (1.0.2.GA) April 2 2008]
at org.sonar.jpa.session.AbstractDatabaseConnector.createEntityManagerFactory(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:66) ~[sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.jpa.session.AbstractDatabaseConnector.start(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:46) ~[sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.jpa.session.DefaultDatabaseConnector.start(DefaultDatabaseConnector.java:37) ~[sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_21]
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-4.1.2.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startCoreComponents(Platform.java:225) ~[Platform.class:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:161) ~[Platform.class:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:54) ~[PlatformLifecycleListener.class:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [na:1.6.0_21]
```

Answer (score 0):

So did you look into the error? It tells you exactly what is wrong:

```
Wrong column type in sonar.active_rule_param_changes for column new_value. Found: text, expected: mediumtext
```

Alter the column and try again.